# Angularjs - Save blob to a text file not working on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to setup a button button or anchor to download some text into a .txt file. With Jquery I do a simple $('#copy_Output_logs').text(); and my text up correctly in my console. So I setup the href link but I keep getting a blank file. To my understading, since my text is loaded dynamically on click, this wont work.

So I created a function that would execute on click. But my anchor keeps opening a page with this weird URL `"http://localhost:8080/%7B%7B"`. Tried an alternatif way by setting un a ng-click on a button but the download dialog dosent work (which I need), it just redirects to the page with the text.

Here's my code so far:

```
App.controller('Forumlaire_Controller', function ($scope, Shared_Service) {

    $scope.Download = function() {
        return Shared_Service.Service_download();
    } 

})
.config( function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(|blob|):/);
});


App.factory('Shared_Service', function($q) {

    return {

        Service_download: function() {  
            var url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
            var data = $('#copy_Output_logs').text();

            console.log($('#copy_Output_logs').text()) // On ng-click the text showup correctly
            console.log(url.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' }))); //Via ng-click the url generates correctly in the console.

            return url.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' }));

        }

    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<a download="content.txt" href={{ Download() }} target="_blank" >Download</a>
<button ng-click="Download()" >Alternatif</button>
```

ANyone have an idea?

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't working, especially when everything seems to be synchronous. I'd love to see the generated `<a>` HTML. Obviously the button won't work since it's just getting a string back.

Comment: Hey there, still curious to know if I helped your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two usages you gave, the `<button>` for sure won't work,since the "click" event returns a string and nothing is done with it.

The problem with the `<a href="{{ Download() }}">` is that it runs when component is generated. Therefore the value of the `Blob` that was created is very likely to be empty.

In the code below, I changed the logic to update the "a" element when it is being clicked. The rest stayed exactly the same.

```
App.controller('Forumlaire_Controller', function ($scope, Shared_Service) {

    $scope.Download = function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("downloadLink"),
            url = Shared_Service.Service_download();

        a.href = url;
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.download = "filename.txt";
    } 

})
.config( function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(|blob|):/);
});


App.factory('Shared_Service', function($q) {

    return {

        Service_download: function() {  
            var url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
            var data = $('#copy_Output_logs').text();

            console.log($('#copy_Output_logs').text()) // On ng-click the text showup correctly
            console.log(url.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' }))); //Via ng-click the url generates correctly in the console.

            return url.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' }));

        }

    }

});
```

As for the HTML

```
<a href="#" id="downloadLink" ng-click="Download()">Download</a>
```